# Can't get new rows added with Arcpy / InsertCursor

Tags: arcpy, cursor

I'm not getting any errors but can't seem to get these rows added. Everything else in the script works fine.
I only dabble with Python occasionally so please forgive me for missing anything obvious

```
new_rows = [(centpointX, centpointY, distance, TRangle),
            (centpointX, centpointY, distance, LRangle)]
cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(pointshap,
                           ['xfield', 'yfield', 'distance', 'bearing'])
for row in new_rows:
    cursor.insertRow(row)
del cursor
```

Comment: Are you getting errors or the data just isn't getting inserted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to add your point X/Y data as field values rather than to `SHAPE`.

Include your X/Y as tuple in `new_rows`, and add them into `SHAPE@XY` with your Insert Cursor

```
new_rows = [((centpointX, centpointY), distance, TRangle),
            ((centpointX, centpointY), distance, LRangle)]
cursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(pointshap,
                           ['SHAPE@XY', 'distance', 'bearing'])
for row in new_rows:
    cursor.insertRow(row)
del cursor
```

See [Insert Cursor - ArcGIS Desktop Help](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/insertcursor-class.htm).  The Syntax section on that page describes the `SHAPE@XY`, and further down the second Code Sample has an example.